# Is C++17 on windows in alignment with C++17 on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17, c++-concepts

I am trying to port some C++17 code I made on ubuntu (gnu++11)

```
typedef boost::variant<int, float, std::string > Variant;
using Func = std::function<std::vector<unsigned char>(std::vector<Variant>)>;  

void addexecutorfunc( Func callback, const auto&...args )
{
    std::vector<Variant> vec = {args...}; 
    executor.add(vec, std::move(callback));
}
```

this code compiles and works fine on ubuntu, but when trying to compile on windows with visual studio 2017(v141) [ISO C++ Latest Draft Standard(/std:c++latest)], then I get following:

> error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'

I think perhaps it has to do with the Concepts lite not being implemented in current C++17 version or is this wrong?

If I could setup compiler to use auto as parameter and parameter packs, then that would be best, but if this is not possible, then I will have to rewrite my code to follow C++17 windows standard - any suggestions on how to do this without ending up in a template hell

Comment: Assuming you're talking about GCC and MSVC, why not use MinGW?

Comment: I could also just use Cygwin, but I want a clean windows C++ solution

Comment: But the given code does not seem to be a valid even with `gnu++11`. Did you mean `gnu++17`?

Comment: it is valid ofcourse with boost added --- 

makefile snippet:
CC=g++ -g .............files...............
-lboost_regex -D__DEBUG__ -D__MSABI_LONG=long -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_system -lboost_log -lboost_signals -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lpthread -lrt -std=gnu++11 -lcurses -I /tclap-1.2.1/include

Comment: Boost does not provide core language features. The current C++17 proposal does not include the feature you are using. It is expected for C++20 by some. If you want a 'clean' solution you will have to stick to what the standard provides.

Comment: @serup: MinGW IS a clean Windows solution.

Comment: so you are saying what? with regards to my question? of course boost needs to be added - question is NOT about boost and what to do with MinGW please elaborate

Comment: MinGW is (roughly) a port of GCC and some required bits and bobs from Linux to Windows. Stephan T. Lavavej has an up-to-date and very neatly packaged version of it on [his website](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html). It also includes the latest Boost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void addexecutorfunc( Func callback, const auto&...args )
```

`auto` as a parameter to a (non-lambda) function is a GNU extension. It is not part of standard C++17, and is not supported by either of the other two major C++ compilers, Clang and MSVC. Rather unfortunately, GCC seems to allow it in `-std=c++14` mode as well as with `-std=gnu++14`.

The standard C++ equivalent would be a function template

```
template <typename... Ts>
void addexecutorfunc(Func callback, const Ts&... args)
```

which should work as expected.

Comment: do you think that this GNU extension is the same as the Concepts lite? and do you think it will ever be supported by MSVC?

Comment: @serup The Concepts TS allows `auto` in a parameter list, although from memory the semantics differ from what the GNU extension does. Whether this "abbreviated function [template] syntax" should be allowed is a major point of debate within the standard committee at the moment, and it's not clear whether or not will end up being part of C++20. As of the last meeting this was not allowed, but that may change some time in the next 3 years.